# Enabling Optional Features in IIS with PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I just want to enable few  windows optional features in IIS like IIS-WebServerRole, IIS-WebServer, IIS-Metabaseand and few more using powershell. What will be the easiest way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Use :

```
Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName [Your_Feature_Name]
```

Comment: What if i want to enable them all at once so that i don't need to write Enable-windowsOptionalFeature -Online  -Feature_name every single time?

Comment: You can create a function and pass feature as parameter or you can create an array of features and loop inside it. Maybe the `-all` parameter can help you too, you may check this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/dism/enable-windowsoptionalfeature?view=win10-ps#parameters)